# Loading phonegap www folder from server rather than storing locally

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am starting an iphone project using Phonegap.Is it possible to load the www folder from the server side,rather than storing it locally,so we can have the updates automatically.If so ,How do we access the native features.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What distribution model do you intend? If you go for the AppStore route is quite likely that the app will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this. Since In phone cap WWW folder is part of your bundle. And your index.html is responsible for showing all the things.

So all these bindings can be handle on the app end. So you can't do any thing like this.

Comment: it is possible to load the www folder from the server.The issue i am facing is that i cannot access the native features.Is there a way to overcome this ?